# wpf DataGrid RowDetailsTemplate Scroll

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid

```
<DataGrid>
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=test}"></DataGridTextColumn>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
  <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
     <DataGrid Template="{DynamicResource TemplateDataGridPrintAndExport}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
 <DataGrid/>
```

I have a datagrid like above. Datgrid's row detail template also contains a datagrid. Inner datagrid is filled when the parent one's columns are clicked. My problem is this : if the row detail template datagrid is fulfilled and user mouse hovers on it while scrolling parent datagrid the scroll is not working. User should hover the mouse to the main datagriid to scroll. However, it is not user friendly. How can I prevent inner datagrid behaving in such a way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the soultion by trying alternatives :

```
<DataGrid  ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=test}"></DataGridTextColumn>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
  <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
     <DataGrid Template="{DynamicResource TemplateDataGridPrintAndExport}"  IsReadOnly="True" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"  IsEnabled="False"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
 <DataGrid/>
```

The solution is to give  `ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"` attribute to the outer data grid and `IsReadOnly="True" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"  IsEnabled="False"` attributes to inner datagrid. Now it is scrolling smoothly and accoording to the parent datagrid.

Comment: Unfortunately, My inner grid contains a check box. So I could not set `IsEnabled="False"` to inner grid. So any other idea to scroll inner grid accoording to the parent datagrid ?

Comment: This solution is totally non-intuitive yet it works. It's a mystery as to why though.

Answer (score 5):

I would like to propose two alternative solutions, since the chosen one has serious side effects. One of them mentioned by Kaizen - you lose ability to interact with nested DataGrid and its child controls. Second one is the change of appearence of controls in their disabled state.

1. Change `IsReadOnly="True"` to `IsHitTestVisible="False"` in osmanraifgunes' solution. This will fix the appearence side effect, but you still won't be able to interact with inner controls (using mouse). Code:

   ```
   <DataGrid ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False">
       <DataGrid.Columns>
           <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=test}" />
       </DataGrid.Columns>
       <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
               <DataGrid
                   IsHitTestVisible="False"
                   ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"
                   Template="{DynamicResource TemplateDataGridPrintAndExport}" />
           </DataTemplate>
       </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
   </DataGrid>
   ```
2. Catch the tunneling `PreviewMouseWheel` event in the control within `RowDetailsTemplate` and pass it back to parent as a bubbling event. This will effectively make controls within `RowDetailsTemplate` blind only to mouse scrolling, and allow controls above in visual tree to handle it however they want to.
   xaml:

   ```
   <DataGrid ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False">
       <DataGrid.Columns>
           <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=test}" />
       </DataGrid.Columns>
       <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
               <DataGrid
                   PreviewMouseWheel="DataGrid_PreviewMouseWheel"
                   Template="{DynamicResource TemplateDataGridPrintAndExport}" />
           </DataTemplate>
       </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
   </DataGrid>
   ```

code behind:

```cs
        private void DataGrid_PreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Handled)
            {
                return;
            }
            Control control = sender as Control;
            if(control == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            e.Handled = true;
            var wheelArgs = new MouseWheelEventArgs(e.MouseDevice, e.Timestamp, e.Delta)
            {
                RoutedEvent = MouseWheelEvent,
                Source = control
            };
            var parent = control.Parent as UIElement;
            parent?.RaiseEvent(wheelArgs);
        }
```

Comment: I've made a quick fix to your 2nd solution that seemed to work better for me. Feel free to [check it out.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63376366/4099159)

Comment: @LuckyLikey Thank you - I was having the same problem. Parent was always null, and raising the event on the outer grid directly wasn't doing anything. Your solution (VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(control)) was exactly what I needed.

Comment: @SeanWorle Thanks for the feedback, I'm glad it helped. Maybe have a quick read throgh the [`VisualTreeHelper`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper?view=netcore-3.1) Class, as it provides many more useful methods.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using .NET 4.5 and above you can use `VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Pixel"` on the outer grid, which will allow you to scroll by pixels instead of units (items) as that is causing pretty weird behavior when having big inner DataGrid as it starts jumping around.

Then you can just past scrolling event to the parent using `PreviewMouseWheel` event on the inner DataGrid since it is being captured by the inner control.

Xaml:

```
<DataGrid VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Pixel">
    <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DataGrid PreviewMouseWheel="DataGrid_PreviewMouseWheel"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
</DataGrid>
```

cs:

```
private void DataGrid_PreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
    var parent = ((Control)sender).Parent as UIElement;
    parent?.RaiseEvent(new MouseWheelEventArgs(e.MouseDevice, e.Timestamp, e.Delta)
    {
        RoutedEvent = MouseWheelEvent,
        Source = sender
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've used [@Bartłomiej Popielarz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52553355/4099159)'s 2nd approach to make it work.

In my case somehow `control.Parent` always returned `null`. Thats why I've changed the according line to

```cs
    var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(control) as UIElement;
```

Also I've created a attached Property that does the forwarding (better suited for MVVM approaches).

```cs
    public class FixScrollingBehaviorOn
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ParentDataGridProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ParentDataGrid", typeof(DataGrid), typeof(FixScrollingBehaviorOn),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(DataGrid), OnParentDataGridPropertyChanged));

        public static bool GetParentDataGrid(DependencyObject obj)

        {
            return (bool)obj.GetValue(ParentDataGridProperty);
        }

        public static void SetParentDataGrid(DependencyObject obj, bool value)

        {
            obj.SetValue(ParentDataGridProperty, value);
        }

        public static void OnParentDataGridPropertyChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)

        {
            var dataGrid = sender as DataGrid;

            if (dataGrid == null)

            {
                throw new ArgumentException("The dependency property can only be attached to a DataGrid", "sender");
            }

            if (e.NewValue is DataGrid parentGrid)
            {
                dataGrid.PreviewMouseWheel += HandlePreviewMouseWheel;
                parentGrid.SetValue(ScrollViewer.CanContentScrollProperty, false);
            }
            else
            {
                dataGrid.PreviewMouseWheel -= HandlePreviewMouseWheel;

                if (e.OldValue is DataGrid oldParentGrid)
                {
                    oldParentGrid.SetValue(ScrollViewer.CanContentScrollProperty, ScrollViewer.CanContentScrollProperty.DefaultMetadata.DefaultValue);
                }
            }
        }

        private static void HandlePreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)

        {
            if (e.Handled)
            {
                return;
            }
            var control = sender as DataGrid;
            if (control == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            e.Handled = true;
            var wheelArgs = new MouseWheelEventArgs(e.MouseDevice, e.Timestamp, e.Delta)
            {
                RoutedEvent = UIElement.MouseWheelEvent,
                Source = control
            };
            var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(control) as UIElement;
            parent?.RaiseEvent(wheelArgs);
        }
```

Feel free to use this as follows on your inner `DataGrid`. Note that The `ScrollViewer.CanContentScrollProperty` is being set from within the AttachedProperty, which may not be everyone's favourite approach.

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=test}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DataGrid
                attachedProperties:FixScrollingBehaviorOn.ParentDataGrid="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"
                Template="{DynamicResource TemplateDataGridPrintAndExport}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Xaml :

```
<DataGrid ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=test}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DataGrid
                PreviewMouseWheel="DataGrid_PreviewMouseWheel"
                Template="{DynamicResource TemplateDataGridPrintAndExport}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
</DataGrid>
```

Code behind :

```
private void DataGrid_PreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
  DataGrid dg = new DataGrid();
            if (sender is DataGrid)
            {
                dg = (DataGrid)sender;
            }
            dg.IsEnabled = false;
            await Task.Delay(200);
            dg.IsEnabled = true;
}
```

Comment: why the creation of a new DataGrid if you only want to update the existing datagrid? Also I consider it very bad practice to shortly disable the Grid, to allow for scrolling.